# Автоматические включение стриминга через ffmpeg на Linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

Всем привет! Возникла проблема со стримингом на Linux (Ubuntu 20.04)... Стриминг работает отлично, но есть возникнет небольшое прерываение с соеденнением до стриминг площадки то ffmpeg прекращает свою работу со следующей информацией:

```
[flv @ 0x557851d39200] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x557851d39200] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
```

Как сделать так что бы не перезапускать врусную эту команду (указана ниже), а система сама отслеживала прерывания работы и делала попытки включения стриминга?

```
ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i "{source-1}" -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -c:a libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 -c:v copy -threads 2 -bufsize 512k -f flv "{rtmps://link-1/key}"
```

Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Можно бесконечный цикл навесить `while true; do ffmpeg -re ... ; sleep 1; done`. Есть еще вариант навесить watchdog который будет следить за процессом и перезапускать его.

Comment: Есть еще такой [ответ](https://superuser.com/a/1050499/1009290)